# how to product details from API

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I am trying to get order details to my confirmation email but my not getting product name. I have used the below code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="<?php echo "Gionee 5.45 4G Smartphone" ?>">   
<th>Orderdetails</th>
    <td>".$_REQUEST['product_name"']."</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

perhaps there a typo in the array key - a stray double quote at the end of `product_name"`?

```
".$_REQUEST['product_name"']."
```

If that's the issue, you can remove the stray quote:

```
".$_REQUEST['product_name']."
```

You might want to `print_r` the `$_REQUEST` array to check if the keys are what you expect.

```
<pre>     
    <?php print_r($_REQUEST) ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="<?php echo "Gionee 5.45 4G Smartphone" ?>"><br>

Comment: <tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<td>".$_REQUEST['first_name']."</td>
</tr>